# Linear data imputation conversion to bilinear interpolation in Python?

Tags: geotiff-tiff, interpolation, modis, satellite, missing-data

I have a project where the task is to impute missing data values from a modis TIF file using Bilinear interpolation.

I tried to use linear interpolation to impute the missing values, but trying to figure out what I would have to do in my code to change it to 'bilinear'. My code is:

```
# creating a variable check which has a tif file which missing data:
img = rasterio.open('MOD11A1_LST_Month_1km_2000_2.tif')
print(check)
# Plotting image
figure(figsize=(6, 6), dpi=80) # size of image
show(img);
```

[image]

```
# Imputation algorithm:
# Fill Missing Rows with Data
# This script shows how to read an image where certain rows have missing data (i.e. 0) 
# and fill that with the average of adjacent rows.


filename = r'/Users/Bilal/Downloads/MOD11A1_LST_Month_1km_2000_2-2.tif'
dataset = rasterio.open(filename)
metadata = dataset.meta
red = dataset.read(1)

# converting the nans to 0 for easy manipulation
red[np.isnan(red)] = 0

# The following returns an array where each item is True/False based on the condition `where=0`

result = np.all(red,axis=1,where=0)

# creating a function which takes an array and an index as input:
def average_rows(array, index):
    result = np.round(np.mean( np.array([array[index[0]-1], array[index[0]+1] ]), axis=0 ))
    array[index] = result
    
for index, x in np.ndenumerate(result):
    if (x and index[0] != 0 and index[0] != (dataset.height - 1)):
        average_rows(red, index) #calling the function

# outputting the imputated tif file on my local machine:
output_filename = r'/Users/Bilal/Downloads/MOD11A1_LST_Month_1km_2000_2-2_fixed.tif'
metadata.update({'driver': 'GTiff'})
rgb_dataset = rasterio.open(output_filename, 'w', **metadata)
rgb_dataset.write(red, 1)
rgb_dataset.close()

# converting tif file before imputation into a numpy array:
check_null = rxr.open_rasterio(check_before_imp)
arr_before = np.array(check_null)

# finding the nulls before imputation:
np.sum(np.count_nonzero(np.isnan(arr_before))) 
>> 3867

# converting tif file after imputation into a numpy array:
check_after_imp = r'/Users/Bilal/Downloads//MOD11A1_LST_Month_1km_2000_2-2_fixed.tif'
dataset_after= rasterio.open(check_after_imp)
figure(figsize=(6, 6), dpi=80) # size of image
show(dataset_after)
```

[image]

```
#converting the fixed tif file into an array:
check_null_after = rxr.open_rasterio(check_after_imp)
arr_after = np.array(check_null_after)

# sum of null data after the impuation:
np.sum(arr_after==0)
>> 69
```

Reference:
https://spatialthoughts.com/2020/06/17/fix-nodata-values/

Comment: Your second image **is** the first image.  What is the second image supposed to be?

Comment: sorry about that, I thought I added both the images but let me share a drive link for first and second image. Second image is after data imputation with still some missing values.

I think if I do bilinear then it would help me knock off all the missing data, thanks for your comment.


Link for 1st image before imputation: 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/126J2DPTWP9qlV6Za8hCySEMSOCFF-0Di/view?usp=sharing

Link for 2nd image after imputation:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/166n90EGeTGNGYmKo31NTXAKqNbt0AMao/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You really need to add images to the Question using the SE editor. There aren't many who will violate best security practice by following links, downloading files, and viewing them.

Comment: @vince actually I cannot edit my own question I don't know why otherwise I would have done it. I am a new member so still learning things :)

Comment: You couldn't Edit with an edit in queue, one which fixed the formatting error that prevented display. You should be able to edit now.

Comment: @vince oh wow I am able to edit now, thanks so much.